# use the given information to find A (matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

[image]

I'm sorry guys, but i found nothing in my preceding section about solving an equation for a matrix variable like this, i understand each of the symbols, but what am I even supposed to do here? can you cancel out the inverse by taking the inverse of both sides, subtracting I and then dividing by 2?

Comment: That seems like a good idea.

Comment: That is what you need to do.(1)to take inverse of both sides (2) subtract I from both sides and lastly (3) divide by 2 . So you get A (matrix).

Comment: yes. alright ill do that and see how my answer matches in back.

Comment: wee i got it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sort of on the right track. Your situation is as follows:
\begin{align*}
(I+2A)^{-1} & = B\\
I+2A & = B^{-1}\\
2A & = B^{-1}-I\\
A& = \frac{1}{2}\left(B^{-1}-I\right).
\end{align*}

So this problem is all about doing matrix algebra and finding inverse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution. I am sorry ,but I am not good with Codecogs Typing.

![gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezvv4.gif)